# AngularFire - query with startAt/endAt doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

**Version info**

Angular : 1.5.8
  Firebase : 3.2.1
  AngularFire : 2.0.1

**Test Case**

```
var path = {};
    path.users ='/users'

var reference = {};
    reference.users = firebase.database().ref(path.users).startAt(0).endAt(10)

$scope.items ={}
$scope.items.users = $firebaseArray(reference.users);

$scope.items.users.$loaded().then(function(object){
    console.log(object);
});
```

**Expected behavior**

Creates a Query with the specified starting point.

**Actual behavior**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$loaded()` and `console.log()` for debugging the loading of your data when using AngularFire.

Instead bind the users to the scope (you already do that) and then show them in your HTML with:

```
<pre>{{ items.users | json }}</pre>
```

The AngularFire documentation covers this under [Handling Asynchronous Operations](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/introduction-to-angularfire.md#handling-asynchronous-operations):

> The easiest way to log the data is to print it within the view using Angular's `json filter. AngularFire tells the Angular compiler when it has finished loading the data, so there is no need to worry about when it be available.
>
> ```
> <pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
> ```